# React components/style guide overview

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I have a React application with quite a large amount of UI components. To keep all these components visible for myself and other colleague's we have a screen/style guide that renders most of the components with some pseudo data. You could think of this page as a simple overview with buttons, headers, input fields, forms et cetera.

This idea is obviously nice, but, in most situations after a while it's not maintained and or updated anymore and gets out of sync with the actual components.

I understand that my question is a bit broad, but I'm wondering if there are certain tools that could potentially help to automate this. So I'm thinking about something that would basically look at all the components available and render it in the style-guide with some example data.

Comment: Have you taken a look at https://storybook.js.org/? You can create 'Knobs' which allow you to pass some data so developers can see how the component deals with different use cases

Comment: @Jetchy That looks really interesting, thank you! I've also just found out about https://github.com/styleguidist/react-styleguidist.